# Query every liked object using FQL

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-fql

I'm trying to query every object which the user has liked since joining facebook by running this query:

```
SELECT user_id, object_id, post_id FROM like WHERE user_id=me()
```

This query runs fine and returns some results, but the number of them is a lot less than I estimated. I tried it on different, real user accounts, and for a friend of mine who has joined facebook around 2006 the number of returned results is still only around 65.

I tried this query through the official javascript sdk and through the graph api explorer which gave identical results.

The [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/like/) doesn't state any limit imposed upon querying the like table.

Is there anything, I should be aware when doing a query on this table?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

According to [this documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream/) :

> Each query of the stream table is limited to the previous 30 days or
>   50 posts, whichever is greater, however you can use time-specific
>   fields such as created_time along with FQL operators (such as < or >)
>   to retrieve a much greater range of posts.

Although not explicitly mentioned in the doucmentation for likes, I guess this will be the same limit. So try to add created_time in a where clause.